# How to restart nginx service in Docker nginx image (`service nginx restart`) without container stopping?

Tags: docker, nginx, cloud

I've been experimenting with `nginx` using Docker image `nginx`.

```
docker run -d --name nginx nginx
docker exec -ti nginx bash
# <edit /etc/nginx/conf.d files>
```

Now in order to load the edited `/etc/nginx/conf.d` files, I execute `service nginx restart`, which causes the container to stop, since the init process (`nginx`) terminated. Thus, I need to execute `docker start nginx` and `docker exec -ti nginx bash` to resume.

Is there any way to restart `nginx` to have it load the edited config files without also stopping the container?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call NGINX again with the **-s** [command line](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/) parameter.

For example, **/usr/bin/nginx -s stop** will stop the NGINX server.

the other signals using with -s command are:

- stop
- quit
- reopen
- reload

The [reload command](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/nginx-start-stop-restart) keeps the Nginx server running as it reloads updated configuration files. If Nginx notices a syntax error in any of the configuration files, the reload is aborted and the server keeps running based on old config files. Reloading is safer than restarting Nginx.

example:
**/usr/bin/nginx -s reload**

Answer (score 7):

`nginx -t` to check config is good

`nginx -s reload` to reload config without restart